# Why does it emphasize "open interval"?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[image]

A maximal integral curve is one that cannot be extended to an integral curve on any larger open interval.

Why does it emphasize "open interval"?

I think the definition as follow is better.

A maximal integral curve is one that cannot be extended to an integral curve on any larger interval.

Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

By the existence theorem for ordinary differential equations a solution always exists on a (possibly small) open neighborhood of any point. Thus it can always be extended to an open interval. If it could be extended to a boundary point of the interval,then it would also extend beyond that to a slightly larger open interval. So, when talking about maximally defined solutions, it makes sense to consider open intervals only.